# Integrate KCFinder with CKeditor - file paths wrong?

Tags: ckeditor, kcfinder

I've been pulling my hair out for like 20 hours trying to get a file manager into ckeditor. I ahve it all working but it isn't managing file paths right, or its directory structure. As if its base URL for uploads is just off. Perhaps one of the smart people can shed some light on this.
Edit page:
http://prospectsontherize.com/admin/edit_content.php?page=home

Tried forcing the root URL in config.php of kcfinder:

```
'uploadURL' => "/upload",
'uploadDir' => "/home/content/24/11515624/html/kcfinder/upload",
```

Initiating the filemanager in ckeditor in its config.js:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
```

---

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a tutorial up here:
http://www.fossfolks.com/how-to/integrate-kcfinder-with-ckeditor-in-wordpress/

with a walkthrough on how I use it here:
http://www.fossfolks.com/how-to/using-kc-finder-once-its-installed/

I still forget how to do it and have to keep reading my own walkthrough...  :P